# Could not Instantiate SessionProvider

Tags: c#, umbraco-ucommerce

I am using UConnector to download orders and update the status. The actual download is working as expected but when I try to update the status I am receiving an error. I have commented on the line causing the error in the code. I was hoping someone could tell me what I am missing?

My Component.config

```
<configuration>
 <components>
    <component
        id="SessionProvider"
        service="UCommerce.EntitiesV2.ISessionProvider, UCommerce"
        type="UCommerce.EntitiesV2.SessionProvider, UCommerce"/>
    <component id="UCommerce.DataMappingsTag"
        service="UCommerce.EntitiesV2.IContainsNHibernateMappingsTag, UCommerce"
        type="UCommerce.EntitiesV2.MappingAssemblyTag, UCommerce"/>
    <component id="OrderService"
        service="UCommerce.Transactions.IOrderService, UCommerce"
        type="UCommerce.Transactions.OrderService, UCommerce"/>
    <component id="Repository"
        service="UCommerce.EntitiesV2.IRepository`1, UCommerce"
        type="UCommerce.EntitiesV2.Repository`1, UCommerce"/>
</components>
</configuration>
```

Code

```
var orderService = ObjectFactory.Instance.Resolve<IOrderService>(); 
//var newOrderStatus = OrderStatus.Get((int)OrderStatusCode.Processing);  //This line
var newOrderStatus = OrderStatus.All().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Processing");  //OR this line give the same error
orderService.ChangeOrderStatus(item, newOrderStatus);
```

Error:

> ComponentActivator: could not instantiate
>   UCommerce.EntitiesV2.SessionProvider

InnerException:

> {"No component for supporting the service
>   UCommerce.Infrastructure.Configuration.CommerceConfigurationProvider
>   was found"}

Stack Trace:

> at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstanceCore(ConstructorCandidate
>   constructor, Object[] arguments, Type implType) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstance(CreationContext
>   context, ConstructorCandidate constructor, Object[] arguments) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.Instantiate(CreationContext
>   context) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(CreationContext
>   context) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(CreationContext
>   context, Burden burden) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.CreateInstance(CreationContext
>   context, Boolean trackedExternally) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.ScopedLifestyleManager.<>n__FabricatedMethod3(CreationContext
>   , Boolean ) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.ScopedLifestyleManager.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Action`1
>   afterCreated) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.Scoped.DefaultLifetimeScope.GetCachedInstance(ComponentModel
>   model, ScopedInstanceActivationCallback createInstance) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.ScopedLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context, IReleasePolicy releasePolicy) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext
>   context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired,
>   Burden& burden) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context, Boolean instanceRequired) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.ResolveFromKernelByType(CreationContext
>   context, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.ResolveFromKernel(CreationContext
>   context, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.ResolveCore(CreationContext
>   context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel
>   model, DependencyModel dependency) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel
>   model, DependencyModel dependency) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateConstructorArguments(ConstructorCandidate
>   constructor, CreationContext context) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.Instantiate(CreationContext
>   context) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(CreationContext
>   context) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(CreationContext
>   context, Burden burden) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.CreateInstance(CreationContext
>   context, Boolean trackedExternally) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.ScopedLifestyleManager.<>n__FabricatedMethod3(CreationContext
>   , Boolean ) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.ScopedLifestyleManager.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Action`1
>   afterCreated) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.Scoped.DefaultLifetimeScope.GetCachedInstance(ComponentModel
>   model, ScopedInstanceActivationCallback createInstance) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.ScopedLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context, IReleasePolicy releasePolicy) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext
>   context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired,
>   Burden& burden) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context, Boolean instanceRequired) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultGenericHandler.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context, Boolean instanceRequired) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Resolve(CreationContext
>   context) at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(IHandler
>   handler, Type service, IDictionary additionalArguments, IReleasePolicy
>   policy) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(Type
>   service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy) at
>   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary
>   arguments) at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.ResolveT at
>   UCommerce.Infrastructure.ObjectFactory.ResolveT at
>   UCommerce.EntitiesV2.OrderStatus.GetRepo() at
>   UCommerce.EntitiesV2.OrderStatus.All() at
>   SiteConnector.Classes.OrdersListToCalClub.Send(IEnumerable`1 input)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I did get a step further by adding a reference to the ucommerce.pipelines dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out you actually need a lot more dll's then you would think.
Here are two screenshots of the ones I'm including (references and lib folder in the project). I'm integrating with sitecore, but you can replace those dll's with the Umbracco counterparts I suppose.

Here's the code I'm using to update the order status. The list contains orderlines in my case (and I'm saving a list in azure storage, so you'll see some dll's for that as well).

```
ISession session = new SessionProvider("connectionstring").GetSession();
OrderStatus status = session.Query<OrderStatus>().FirstOrDefault(os => os.Name.Equals("Processing"));     
foreach (PurchaseOrder order in list.Select(o => o.PurchaseOrder))
{
    order.OrderStatus = status;
    session.Save(order);               
} 
session.Flush();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is very similar to the code I finally got to in the end. See my answer. There seems to be very little documentation to UCommerce unless you have found something I haven't?

Comment: As a side note its Sitecore 8 and UCommerce I am working with as well have you found much documentation on using the two together?

Comment: Not really, some bits and pieces. mostly I combined the uconnector samples and the code from the masterclass. when that proved insuficient I  started adding references to dll's being used by ucommerce in my site.

Answer (score 1):

This updates the Purchase Order to whatever status it find in `ord.OrderStatusName`  Also I have found that not clearing the session can slow thing down big time if you are processing over 200 records.

```
foreach (CcOrder ord in input)
{
    PurchaseOrder poOrder =
    _session.Query<PurchaseOrder>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.OrderNumber == ord.OrderId);
    OrderStatus newOrderStatus = _session.Query<OrderStatus>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == ord.OrderStatusName);

    if (poOrder == null || newOrderStatus == null) continue; //If one or both not found go to next
    poOrder.OrderStatus = newOrderStatus;
    _session.Save(poOrder);
    _session.Flush();
    _session.Clear();
}
```